# (coding to get) Python code completion to choose from a list of allowable strings

Tags: python, code-completion

Assume a simple function:

```
def example(formula="")
    ...
```

Where the argument "formula" should be one of 2400 possible chemical formulas.
Would there be a way to get code completion for choosing one string from a list of 2400 strings?

First idea was to chose from a list of class attributes.
However, I can not use the **dir**()  method.
These formula strings are often invalid for use as attribute names.

I don't see another method that would list a choice without using attributes of something.

Thanks

Comment: Code completion is a feature of your editor or coding environment. Could you specify which one you are using?

Comment: My target is Jupyter, but I also use PyCharm. I guess both start by looking the _dir_().

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. I would be happy for argument code completion. But I would also be happy with class attributes code completion. This explain my comment on _dir_(). I don't know the analogue for picking arguments possible values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enums, which PyCharm for instance code completes just nicely, especially if you use type hinting.

```
import enum

class ChemFormula(enum.Enum):
    Chlorine = "cl2"
    Hydrogen = "h2"
    Water = "h2o"


def example(formula: ChemFormula) -> None:
    ....
```

Comment: enums don't need commas. In fact, they'll turn the values into tuples, which is undesired

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a simple solution. I tested it on a simple example in Jupyter, and this will be useful. I just don't see the need for enum.Enum as it also works without in Jupyter. Only one drawback: I need to create valid attributes automatically for the 2400 formulas in my database and this is not so obvious.

Comment: I've fixed the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get a random string from a list of strings?

```
 from random import choice

 formulas = ['f1', 'f2']
 formula = choice(formulas)
 example(formula = formula)
```

If not, then simply indexing (`formulas[int]`) should do the trick.

Comment: I don't need a random choice. I need the stuff to get completion useful in my case. I don't understand your suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I figured, seems like you found an answer :)